# Birthday Paradox - Function with input variable

Tags: r, function, prompt, birthday-paradox

I am trying to simulate the probability that more than two students have the same birthday in a room full on n people.  Currently I think my code is working properly, although I have to initially just run the first line of code to select my n value, then run the rest of the code separately (see below)

```
n = as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter the number of students in a room:"))

sims = 10000
x = numeric(sims)

for (i in 1:sims){
s = sample(1:365, n, replace=TRUE)
x[i] = n - length(unique(s))}

samebday = length(which(x>0))/length(x)
samebday
```

How would I tidy this up so that the variable `n` is contained within the function?  As soon as I try to convert this to a function as follows:

```
bday.prob = function(n){...}
```

then errors start occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the code you wrote before and simply wrap it into a function, you can do so by letting `n` and `sims` be user-defined input variables, like @42- mentioned.

Below is my solution, with minimal changes from what you provided:

```
bday.prob = function(n, sims){
  #' @param n is the number of students in a room; user-defined
  #' @param sims is the number of trials; user-defined

  x = numeric(sims)
  for (i in 1:sims){
    s = sample(1:365, n, replace=TRUE)
    x[i] = n - length(unique(s))
  }
  samebday = length(which(x > 0))/length(x)
  return(samebday)
}
```

Use the function as follows:

```
bday.prob(n=<User choice>, sims=<User choice>)
```

or

```
bday.prob(n=as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter the number of students in a room:")), sims=100)
## Enter the number of students in a room: <User choice>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't know that this function already exists in the stats package:

```
pbirthday(30, classes = 365, coincident = 2)
[1] 0.7063162
```

There's also a quantile version: `qbirthday`

Wrap it in a function, but don't add the parameter `n` to the argument list if you are also going to do th einlut inside the function:

```
 # copied from my console
 bfun <- function(){ n = as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter the number of students in a room:"))
+ print( pbirthday(n, classes = 365, coincident = 2) )
+ }
> bfun()
Enter the number of students in a room:30
[1] 0.7063162
```

Comment: Thank you! Useful to know there is a function for coincidences.

Comment: Think of it as a function on random samples with replacement.